# Deploying VueJS & DRF app on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vue.js, architecture, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF backend with 3 different VueJS app for the frontend. The application is tenant-like architecture so SuperAdmin, Admin and User panels are the 3 different VueJS apps.

I have currently deployed it in a VPS (Amazon Lightsail) and kept the static apps in Buckets (Amazon S3) with Static Hosting enabled. But now the application needs to move in production and I am looking for easy and maintainable way to deploy the tenants over and over again to any AWS service available.

I have considered Elastic Beanstalk for the DRF app, with 3 buckets per tenant for the frontend apps. The urls would look like:

1. example.com (landing page)
2. api.example.com (DRF root)
3. tenant1.example.com (landing page for the tenant to choose one of 3 interfaces)
4. tenant1-su.example.com (superadmin interface)
5. tenant1-ad.example.com (admin interface)
6. tenatn1-uz.example.com (end user interface)

But using this way, there would be a lot of work with different AWS components. May be I could write a script to automate the repetitive tasks, but will that be enough to manage them in long run?

Do you have anything else that you suggest instead of the current architecture I have in mind?

If anyone else has done similar thing, or if anyone has the script for deployment done before, any pointers would be useful.